# Remove invalid UTF-8 characters from a string

Tags: json, unicode, go

I get this on json.Marshal of a list of strings:

```
json: invalid UTF-8 in string: "...ole\xc5\"
```

The reason is obvious, but how can I delete/replace such strings in Go? I've been reading docst on `unicode` and `unicode/utf8` packages and there seems no obvious/quick way to do it.

In Python for example you have methods for it where the invalid characters can be deleted, replaced by a specified character or strict setting which raises exception on invalid chars. How can I do equivalent thing in Go?

UPDATE: I meant the reason for getting an exception (panic?) - illegal char in what json.Marshal expects to be valid UTF-8 string.

(how the illegal byte sequence got into that string is not important, the usual way - bugs, file corruption, other programs that do not conform to unicode, etc)

Comment: How is the reason obvious? I'd guess you have a latin1 (or some other variant of ISO8859) string there in which case you don't want a function to swallow these characters but instead convert them to UTF-8 before continuing ...

Comment: In Go 1.2, the json parser will accept malformed UTF-8. It will replace malformed bytes with a replacement glyph.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    s := "a\xc5z"
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)
    if !utf8.ValidString(s) {
        v := make([]rune, 0, len(s))
        for i, r := range s {
            if r == utf8.RuneError {
                _, size := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s[i:])
                if size == 1 {
                    continue
                }
            }
            v = append(v, r)
        }
        s = string(v)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)
}
```

Output:

```
"a\xc5z"
"az"
```

> [Unicode Standard](http://unicode.org/)
>
> [FAQ - UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 & BOM](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)
>
> Q: Are there any byte sequences that are not generated by a UTF? How
>   should I interpret them?
>
> A: None of the UTFs can generate every arbitrary byte sequence. For
>   example, in UTF-8 every byte of the form 110xxxxx2 must be followed
>   with a byte of the form 10xxxxxx2. A sequence such as <110xxxxx2
>   0xxxxxxx2> is illegal, and must never be generated. When faced with
>   this illegal byte sequence while transforming or interpreting, a UTF-8
>   conformant process must treat the first byte 110xxxxx2 as an illegal
>   termination error: for example, either signaling an error, filtering
>   the byte out, or representing the byte with a marker such as FFFD
>   (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER). In the latter two cases, it will continue
>   processing at the second byte 0xxxxxxx2.
>
> A conformant process must not interpret illegal or ill-formed byte
>   sequences as characters, however, it may take error recovery actions.
>   No conformant process  may use irregular byte sequences to encode
>   out-of-band information.

Comment: While most likely completely irrelevant, your example might strip out completely correct encoded *Unicode Replacement Characters* (`"\xef\xbf\xbd"`) if the string also contains broken UTF8 sequences.

Comment: @ANisus: The assumption is that people have read the Unicode Standard.

Comment: My comment was just meant as trivia. My function would also strip away the replacement characters together with the illegal sequences (it is after all my +1 ;) ). I just said that the legal byte sequence of "\xef\xbf\xbd", which json.Marshal will accept, will also be stripped away. Not sure how the Unicode Standard would disagree with that.

Comment: @ANisus: If you want to, you can keep any replacement characters. See my revised answer.

Comment: @peterSO question: In the above context, does `unicode.ReplacementChar` bear a similarity to `utf8.RuneError` ?

Comment: @Roylee: Same thing, different names: [`unicode.ReplacementChar = '\uFFFD'`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#pkg-constants) and [`utf8.RuneError = '\uFFFD'`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#pkg-constants).

Answer (score 26):

**In Go 1.13+, you can do this:**

```
strings.ToValidUTF8("a\xc5z", "")
```

---

**In Go 1.11+, it's also very easy to do the same using the [Map function](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Map) and [utf8.RuneError](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#pkg-constants) like this:**

```
fixUtf := func(r rune) rune {
    if r == utf8.RuneError {
        return -1
    }
    return r
}

fmt.Println(strings.Map(fixUtf, "a\xc5z"))
fmt.Println(strings.Map(fixUtf, "posic�o"))
```

**Output:**

```
az
posico
```

**Playground:** [Here](https://play.golang.org/p/Flcsae3oFbB).

Comment: FYI, ```strings.ToValidUTF8``` didn't make it into Go 1.12, but looks like it is planned for Go 1.13:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25805

Comment: NB: `strings.ToValidUTF8` doesn't touch the `\x00` char, so it won't help with, e.g.  `invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00` with postgres. You need to handle the case expicitly: `strings.ToValidUTF8(t, strings.ReplaceAll(s, "\x00", ""), "")`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861479/how-to-detect-when-bytes-cant-be-converted-to-string-in-go/34863211#34863211), could be

```go
s = string([]rune(s))
```

[Example](https://play.golang.org/p/QSoxtNIFQkW):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    s := "...ole\xc5"
    fmt.Println(s, utf8.Valid([]byte(s)))
    // Output: ...ole� false

    s = string([]rune(s))
    fmt.Println(s, utf8.Valid([]byte(s)))
    // Output: ...ole� true
}
```

Even though the result doesn't look "pretty", it still nevertheless converts the string into a valid UTF-8 encoding.