# Slicing in Golang leads to blank terminal and messed up threads

Tags: linux, go

Hey I am trying to automate a tool to do my recon I am using url to store url with `https://` but there's a tool `whois and sublist3r` that needs the address without `https://` so I sliced the string but when I run the tool it crashes out and blanks out my terminal I can type but can't see the output.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
)

var url string
var wg sync.WaitGroup
var ip string
var nsurl string
func nikto(outChan chan<- []byte) {
    cmd := exec.Command("nikto", "-h", url)
    bs, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    outChan <- bs
    wg.Done()
}

func whois(outChan chan<- []byte) {

    cmd := exec.Command("whois",nsurl)
    bs, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    outChan <- bs
    wg.Done()
}
func nmap (outChan chan<-[]byte) {
    cmd := exec.Command("nmap","-sC","-sV","-oA","nmap",ip)
//  cmd := exec.Command("nmap","-h")
    bs,err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    }
    outChan <- bs
    wg.Done()
    }
func sniper(outChan chan<-[]byte){
    cmd:=exec.Command("sniper","-t",url)
    bs,err := cmd.Output()
    if err!=nil{
    log.Fatal(err)
    }
    outChan <- bs
    wg.Done()
    }
func sublist3r(outChan chan<-[]byte) {
    cmd := exec.Command("sublist3r","-d",nsurl)
    bs,err := cmd.Output()
    if err!=nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    }
    outChan <- bs
    wg.Done()
    }

func inspy (outChan chan<-[]byte){
    cmd := exec.Command("inspy","--empspy","/opt/wordlists/wordlists/title-list-large.txt",url)
    bs,err := cmd.Output()
    if err!=nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    }
    outChan <- bs
    wg.Done()
    }
func wig (outChan chan<-[]byte){
    //nsurl = url[8:]
    cmd := exec.Command("wig",url)
    bs,err := cmd.Output()
    if err!=nil{
    log.Fatal(err)
    }
    outChan <- bs
    wg.Done()
    }
func main() {
    outChan := make(chan []byte)
    fmt.Printf("Please input URL with https:// \n")
    fmt.Scanln(&url)
    fmt.Printf("Please input IP \n")
    fmt.Scanln(&ip)
    nsurl = url[8:]
    wg.Add(1)
    go nikto(outChan)
    wg.Add(1)
    go whois(outChan)
    wg.Add(1)
    go nmap(outChan)
    wg.Add(1)
    go sniper(outChan)
    wg.Add(1)
    go sublist3r(outChan)
    wg.Add(1)
    go inspy(outChan)
    wg.Add(1)
    go wig(outChan)
    for i := 0; i <7 ; i++ {
        bs := <-outChan
        fmt.Println(string(bs))
    }

    close(outChan)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Which line/function causes your problem? Please reduce the code sample to the minimum size that still creates the error.

Comment: Since you have an unbuffered channel and the number of goroutines you start is also the number of times you read from the channel, you really don't need a waitgroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if "it crashes out and blanks out my terminal"
then probably the output from the program has characters that your terminal reacts badly to

add "unicode/utf8" to imports and try replacing

```
fmt.Println(string(bs))
```

with

```
if utf8.ValidString(bs) {
   fmt.Printf("%v\n",bs)
} else {
   fmt.Printf("warning, loosing output")
}
```

See this answer on how to clean output to make it readable
[Remove invalid UTF-8 characters from a string (Go lang)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401873/remove-invalid-utf-8-characters-from-a-string-go-lang)