# bytes to string conversion with invalid characters

Tags: string, go, utf-8

I need to parse UDP packets which can be invalid or contain some errors. I would like to replace invalid characters with `.` after a bytes to string conversion, in order to display the content of the packets.

How can I do it? This is my code:

```
func main() {
   a := []byte{'a', 0xff, 0xaf, 'b', 0xbf}
   s := string(a)
   s = strings.Replace(s, string(0xFFFD), ".", 0)

   fmt.Println("s: ", s) // I would like to display "a..b."
   for _, r := range s {
      fmt.Println("r: ", r)
   }
   rs := []rune(s)
   fmt.Println("rs: ", rs)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root problem with your approach is that the result of type converting `[]byte` to `string` does not have any `U+FFFD`s in it: this type-conversion only copies bytes from the source to the destination, verbatim.
Just as byte slices, strings in Go are not obliged to contain UTF-8-encoded text; they can contain any data, including opaque binary data which has nothing to do with text.

But some operations on strings—namely [type-converting them to `[]rune`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type) and [iterating over them using `range`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_range)—*do* interpret strings as UTF-8-encoded text.
That is precisely where you got tripped: your `range` debugging loop attempted to *interpret* the string, and each time another attempt at decoding a properly encoded code point failed, `range` yielded a replacement character, `U+FFFD`.
To reiterate, the string obtained by the type-conversion does not contain the characters you wanted to get replaced by your regexp.

As to how to actually make a valid UTF-8-encoded string out of your data, you might employ a two-step process:

1. Type-convert your byte slice to a string—as you already do.
2. Use any means of interpreting a string as UTF-8—replacing U+FFFD which will dynamically appear during this process—as you're iterating.

Something like this:

```golang
var sb strings.Builder
for _, c := range string(b) {
  if c == '\uFFFD' {
    sb.WriteByte('.')
  } else {
    sb.WriteRune(c)
  }
}
return sb.String()
```

A note on performance: since type-converting a `[]byte` to `string` copies memory—because strings are immutable while slices are not—the first step with type-conversion might be a waste of resources for code dealing with large chunks of data and/or working in tight processing loops.
In this case, it may be worth using the [`DecodeRune` function of the `encoding/utf8` package](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode/utf8#DecodeRune) which works on byte slices.
An example from its docs can be easily adapted to work with the loop above.

See also: [Remove invalid UTF-8 characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401873/)

Comment: the value `U+FFFD` is the value of the constant `utf8.RuneError` Which in turns is the value used by the package to tell the caller that the input is not a proper utf8 encoded data. https://pkg.go.dev/unicode/utf8#pkg-constants

Answer (score 5):

@kostix answer is correct and explains very clearly the issue with scanning unicode runes from a string.

Just adding the following remark : if your intention is to view characters only in the ASCII range (printable characters < 127) and you don't really care about other unicode code points, you can be more blunt :

```golang
// create a byte slice with the same byte length as s
var bs = make([]byte, len(s))

// scan s byte by byte :
for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
    switch {
    case 32 <= s[i] && s[i] <= 126:
        bs[i] = s[i]

    // depending on your needs, you may also keep characters in the 0..31 range,
    // like 'tab' (9), 'linefeed' (10) or 'carriage return' (13) :
    // case s[i] == 9, s[i] == 10, s[i] == 13:
    //   bs[i] = s[i]

    default:
        bs[i] = '.'
    }
}


fmt.Printf("rs: %s\n", bs)
```

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/uhVTwWFpXN1)

This function will give you something close to the "text" part of `hexdump -C`.

Comment: Good perspective, actually; +1.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to use [`strings.ToValidUTF8()`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#ToValidUTF8) for this:

> ToValidUTF8 returns a copy of the string s with each run of invalid UTF-8 byte sequences replaced by the replacement string, which may be empty.

It "seemingly" does exactly what you need. Testing it:

```
a := []byte{'a', 0xff, 0xaf, 'b', 0xbf}
s := strings.ToValidUTF8(string(a), ".")
fmt.Println(s)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/SXtrEMhFktX)):

```
a.b.
```

I wrote "seemingly" because as you can see, there's a single dot between `a` and `b`: because there may be 2 bytes, but a single invalid sequence.

Note that you may avoid the `[]byte` => `string` conversion, because there's a [`bytes.ToValidUTF8()`](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#ToValidUTF8) equivalent that operates on and returns a `[]byte`:

```
a := []byte{'a', 0xff, 0xaf, 'b', 0xbf}
a = bytes.ToValidUTF8(a, []byte{'.'})
fmt.Println(string(a))
```

Output will be the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/nDzLx0ViFXG).

If it bothers you that multiple (invalid sequence) bytes may be shrinked into a single dot, read on.

Also note that to inspect arbitrary byte slices that may or may not contain texts, you may simply use [`hex.Dump()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/hex@go1.17.6#Dump) which generates an output like this:

```
a := []byte{'a', 0xff, 0xaf, 'b', 0xbf}
fmt.Println(hex.Dump(a))
```

Output:

```
00000000  61 ff af 62 bf                                    |a..b.|
```

There's your expected output `a..b.` with other (useful) data like the hex offset and hex representation of bytes.

To get a "better" picture of the output, try it with a little longer input:

```
a = []byte{'a', 0xff, 0xaf, 'b', 0xbf, 50: 0xff}
fmt.Println(hex.Dump(a))

00000000  61 ff af 62 bf 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |a..b............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 ff                                          |...|
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/nEk20mXe0cl).

Comment: There's only one "dot" between `a`and `b` - which is misleading if one wants to see precise byte offsets. I think the OP really just wants printable (& unprintable) ASCII bytes. Using UTF-8 tricks over-complicates things.

Comment: @colm.anseo Yes, maybe. But the character `á` is printable and has code `225`: it even fits into a single byte! Yet in UTF-8 it occupies 2 bytes. If you print those 2 bytes for a single char, that also might be misleading. For accurate offsets, `hex.Dump()` should be preferred.

Comment: Agreed. The OP goal is UDP packet inspection - so just wants signal vs. marker bytes to be clearly delineated.