# Error while using proto.Unmarshal for Protocol Buffers data: "string field contains invalid UTF-8

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm working on a Go application that uses Protocol Buffers, and I'm encountering an issue while deserializing the data using `proto.Unmarshal`. The specific error message I'm getting is "string field contains invalid UTF-8".

Here is my deserialization code:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/example/pb" // Import the package containing the Protocol Buffers definition.
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
)

func deserializeData(res_data *pb.ResponseData) (*pb.NotfnMessg, error) {
    notfnMessg := &pb.NotfnMessg{}

    err := proto.Unmarshal(res_data.Payload.GetSerializedMessage(), notfnMessg)
    if err != nil {
        appLogger.Logging().Error("Error Unmarshalling the message: %v", err)
    }
    appLogger.Logging().Info("%v, %v", notfnMessg, res_data.Payload.GetSerializedMessage())
}
```

The `res_data.Payload.GetSerializedMessage()` function returns the serialized message data in a string format. The content of `res_data` is provided below as a demo.

Here's an example of the serialized data stored in `res_data`:

```
msg_hdr:{s_val:"CONFIG_GET_REP"}  payload:{payload_header:{s_val:"SUCCESS"}  serialized_message:"\n\xc3\x0b...<omitted for brevity>.../communication\n*\n\x05title\x12!\n\x17Pi Module ConfigurationZ\x06/title"}
```

As you can see, the serialized message contains binary data, including strings. It appears that there might be invalid UTF-8 characters in one of the string fields, causing the deserialization to fail.

I would like to know how to properly handle this issue and successfully deserialize the data without encountering the "string field contains invalid UTF-8" error.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to handle invalid UTF-8 characters during the deserialization process would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You could edit the `.proto` and change the `string` fields to `bytes` (the two are [wire compatible](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#updating)). Then you can process the resulting bytes yourself ([this answer may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52784785/11810946)).

Comment: You beat me to it, @brits - IMO you should post that as an answer, as that's pretty much the only option here, short of changing the deserialize core to be forgiving

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks - will do (just wanted to look into other potential causes; but it looks like a range of libraries check for valid UTF-8 when decoding but not when encoding, so it's quite possible the issue is with whatever is encoding the data rather than corruption).

Answer (score 1):

When deserializing a `string` field the Go protobuf code ([and others](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/4970#issuecomment-408925726)) validate that strings are UTF-8. When they are not you get the error you are seeing.

As far as I am aware the simplest way around this is to edit the `.proto` and change the `string` fields to `bytes`, then rerun `protoc` (or `buf` etc) to regenerate your `github.com/example/pb`. `string` and `bytes` fields are [wire compatible](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#updating) the difference is in the output types.

This will give you the data as a `[]byte` in Go, you can then process it yourself (e.g. `strings.ToValidUTF8("a\xc5z", "")` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52784785/11810946))

Comment: @Bits thanks for the feedback, but I cannot change the `.proto` file because this file is not only used in this codebase there are also a lot of other codebases in cpp, and python that using this .proto file, I'm aware of this but this is not going to work,

Comment: Have you tried deserializing the same data using cpp? (as per the issue I linked I believe that also validates UTF-8 so I would expect it to also fail). [The guide](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#scalar) states "A string must always contain UTF-8 encoded or 7-bit ASCII text." so I would also investigate the possibility that your message is corrupted.

Comment: well, now I've fixed the problem

Comment: @Jocefyneroot Would you mind sharing your solution? (may help others encountering this in the future).